# How do get current field in a UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

If I click a textbox for a webpage within a UIWebView is there a way to get the name of that textbox?

It seems like I should be able to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, but if I don't already know the name of the field or textbox, it won't be of much use will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it in the iOS webkit, but `document.activeElement` should give you the dom node of the currently focused element, if the user has selected an input field.

You can modify it's contents by setting the `value` attribute of the node.

If the user hasn't selected an input field, then the activeElement might be a `DIV` or `BODY`, or some such. You can check for this by examining the `nodeName` property of the node.

Depending on what kind of node it is, you may have to set the `innerHtml` attribute.

Comment: That was almost the answer.  I had do some looking but I realized that it was just "document.activeElement".  SO I ended up with something like this:

 `code`jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var field = document.activeElement;" 
      "field.value='something';", symbol.data];
 [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString];`code`

If you edit your answer, I'll mark it correct.

Thanks.

Comment: You wanted the name of the node.. without the id field, you're getting the node instance itself, not it's "name." I will edit the answer to reflect what you were actually asking, however. :-)